# How to Remove Last Folder showing first in surch result paths with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, path, windows-search

This is driving my boss crazy. He and I are using virtually identical machines running Windows 7 64-bit and mine does not do it. Is this a setting or some kind of bug or...?

Screenshot:

[image]

The "inc" Showing before the (X:\En... is the name of last folder in the actual path. In other words it is the folder in which the search result is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how the `Folder` column displays the path, it can't be changed.  You can display other columns instead by right-clicking on a column header and clicking `More...`.  There are 2 other options which might interest you: `Folder Path` and `Folder Name`.  `Folder Path` contains what you see in parentheses in the screen shot.  `Folder Name` contains just the name of the containing folder.

You can then drag column headers left or right to reorder them in the results.